# Gap between first element and top of page

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
    body {
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: rgb(41, 11, 22);
    }
    
    nav {
        color: white;
        background-color: rgb(214, 50, 50);
        height: 10vh;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <title>Navbar Animations</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <p>This is a test</p>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But the end result is like this:

[image: website]

Question is: how would I get rid of that gap at the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of the p's margin, you can just remove it:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```